# go-ethereum unit-tests failing (when using `go-test`)

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, state-trie

I cloned go-ethereum from https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum and its test cases from https://github.com/ethereum/tests.git
When I run `go test`, it fails and gives error-

> state_test.go:79: post state root mismatch: got 61b79e0d2bc370a210f5091af0509a1d83661dbda2d9e2abe46b60e884c13c70, want 80dfd03978291076e5ba586b1954191fbc909808cb7719834a57934004c96a6a

and many more errors similar to this. 
I know it is state-error- http://ethereum-tests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_types/state_tests.html

I have been on this for a long time but can't figure it out. 
What might be wrong at my end if tests are failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tests are now commented out.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15598